# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(uu')'\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(uu')'\,dx$$

knowing that $u=u(x)$ and $u'=du/dx$. The primes denote derivatives with respect to  $x$. Additionally, $u(x)\rightarrow0$ and $u'(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Attempt at solution:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(uu')'\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u\frac{d}{dx}(uu')\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (uu')\,du=\quad...$$

Is there any way to continue with integration by parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integration by parts uses $v=uu^\prime$ to get$$[u^2u^\prime]_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^\infty uu^{\prime2}dx,$$but without more information you can't evaluate the last integral in general.